# Exception while try to send async get request during singleton initialisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsjsonserialization

here is my code:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static PanoramaDataManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[PanoramaDataManager alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[sharedInstance requestToService:kPanoramaAPIGetToken withParams:@{@"login" : kPanoramaAPILogin, @"password" : kPanoramaAPIPassword}] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (!connectionError) {
                NSError *error;
                NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                                               error:&error];
                if (!error) {
                    sharedInstance.token = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"token"];
                } else {
                    [BxAlertView showError:error.description];
                }
            } else {
                [BxAlertView showError:connectionError.description];
            }
        }];
    });
    return [sharedInstance autorelease];
}
```

All i want to do is just to send the request to the server to receive the token for all the rest requests during the singleton initialisation. But I have an exception of bad access in the line where I try to set the property. If I try to write `NSError *error = nil;` the app is stopped with the exception of bad access. Any help?

Comment: Remove that `autorelease`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the autorelease at the return;

If you release a static var you lose the value that you address with the pointer.

Comment: you just copied the comment from @ Midhun MP. can you explain , what this will do (remove the autorelease). better to add a explanation in your answer.

Comment: @pawan Nope look at the timestamp I said before

Comment: If you release a static var you lose the value that you address with the pointer.